# Identify negative values in a list without corresponding positive values

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list (or numpy array) containing elements of type `float`, I want to identify those negative elements that don't have a corresponding positive element.

Test cases:

```
[] => []
[10.] => []
[-10.] => [-10.]
[10., -10.] => []
[10., -10., -10.] => [-10.]
[10., -10., -10., 50., 100., -50.] => [-10.]
[10., -10., -10., 50., 100., -50., -200.] => [-10., -200.]
[10., -10., 200., 300., 400., 500., -200., -300., -10.] => [-10.]
[-100., -200., -300.] => [-100., -200., -300.]
[-100., 200., -300., 400., -200.] => [-100., -300.]
```

Comment: `[i for i in lst if i<0 and -i not in lst]`?

Comment: @not_speshal No. The test case [10, -10, -10] gives [-10] whereas your solution gives []

Comment: Are the numbers in the input really floats?  The example you show are integers?  If truly floats, what accuracy do you want to use to determine equality between two floats?

Comment: @itprorh66 Thanks for your comment. They are meant to be of type `float` (I've edited the question to reflect that). If the difference between two elements are less than 1e-5, then consider them equal.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `collections.Counter` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [10, -10, -10, -10, 50, 100, -50, -200]
counter = Counter(lst)
output = list(Counter({k: v-counter.get(-k,0) for k, v in counter.items() if k<0}).elements())

>>> output
[-10, -10, -200]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the parameters this can be solved using some simple loops

```
def filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items):
    pos_numbers = []
    neg_numbers = []
    for item in items:
        if item >= 0:
            pos_numbers.append(item)
        else:
            neg_numbers.append(item)
    for pos_number in pos_numbers:
        if any(np.isclose(-1 * pos_number,neg_numbers)):
            neg_numbers.remove(-1 * pos_number)
    return neg_numbers
```

This uses np.isclose to determine if the values are close to each other and after the loops runs neg_numbers will have the correct values.
This was run using the following tests

```
def test_empty_is_empty(self):
    items = []
    expected = []
    ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items)
    self.assertListEqual(expected,ret_val)
def test_pos_is_empty(self):
    items = [10.]
    expected = []
    ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items)
    self.assertListEqual(expected,ret_val)
def test_one_neg_is_same_neg(self):
    items = [-10.]
    expected = [-10.]
    ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items)
    self.assertListEqual(expected,ret_val)
def test_neg_and_pos_of_neg_is_empty(self):
    items = [10.,-10.]
    expected = []
    ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items)
    self.assertListEqual(expected,ret_val)
def test_two_neg_and_one_pos_is_one_neg(self):
    items = [10.,-10.,-10.]
    expected = [-10.]
    ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items)
    self.assertListEqual(expected,ret_val)
def test_two_neg_and_one_pos_is_one_neg_float(self):
    items = [10.43232,-10.43231,-10.43232]
    expected = [-10.43232]
    ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items)
    self.assertTrue(np.isclose(expected,ret_val).all())
def test_larger_set(self):
    items = [10, -10, -10, 50, 100, -50]
    mult_items = [
        [10., -10., -10., 50., 100., -50.],
        [10., -10., -10., 50., 100., -50., -200.],
        [10., -10., 200., 300., 400., 500., -200., -300., -10.],
        [-100., 200., -300., 400., -200.]
        
    ]
    expected = [
        [-10.],
        [-10.,-200.],
        [-10.],
        [-100.,-300.]
    ]
    for index,item in enumerate(mult_items):
        with self.subTest(item=item):
            ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(item)
            self.assertListEqual(ret_val,expected[index])
        
def test_all_neg(self):
    items = [-100., -200., -300.]
    expected = [-100., -200., -300.]
    ret_val = filter_for_negs_with_no_pos(items)
    self.assertListEqual(expected,ret_val)
```